# Replacing YAML text with yq for a line containing single quotes

Tags: yaml, yq

I'm trying to edit a YAML file to replace several particular values via a bash script.

For example, in the following file, I'd like to change the value of "command" from
`sh -c 'fabric-ca-server init -b admin:adminpw'`
to `sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw'`

Before (Original File):

```
fabric-ca-server:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:amd64-1.4.7
  container_name: fabric-ca-server
  ports:
    - "7054:7054"
  environment:
    - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
  volumes:
    - "./fabric-ca-server:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server"
  command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server init -b admin:adminpw'
```

After (Desired Result):

```
fabric-ca-server:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:amd64-1.4.7
  container_name: fabric-ca-server
  ports:
    - "7054:7054"
  environment:
    - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
  volumes:
    - "./fabric-ca-server:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server"
  command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw'
```

Originally, I used sed like this:
`sed -i "10s/command:.*/command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b $UNVAR:$PWVAR'/" ./docker-compose.yaml` Which works, but is pretty clumsy, since it requires the actual line number (which can change).

I discovered `yq`, which seems much more elegant, but I'm having trouble getting it to work here, because it interprets the `-c` as a flag.  (I tried playing around with '--' to correct this, but didn't figure out how to get it working.)

`yq w -i ./docker-compose.yaml fabric-ca-server.command sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b $TLSCA_UN:$TLSCA_PW'`

Any suggestions on how I could do this correctly with yq?

Comment: I'm assuming you are using https://github.com/mikefarah/yq. Can you post the version details? `yq --version`?

Comment: @Inian Yes - I downloaded it earlier today from github.  I've got yq version 3.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is quite trivial. In [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) the write syntax takes the form

```
yq write [yaml_file] [path_expression] [value] [flags]
```

You were right in identifying the `path_expression`, but just didn't include the right quotes to wrap the replacement text. In most shells (including `bash`) wrapping stuff over double quotes preserves the literal value of the string (except embedded double quotes). So you just need to do

```
yq w docker-compose.yaml fabric-ca-server.command "sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw'"
```

Once you confirm the replacement text is as "expected", add the `-i` tag to make the file change permanent.